# jdk.vm.ci.common.JVMCIError: no JVMCI compiler selected with Java9 but not in Java10

Tags: java, jvm, java-9, java-10

I am trying to experiment with the JVMCI and its existence in the JDK [using the following from a mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/graal-dev/2016-June/004434.html)-

```
private static void JVMCIQueries() {
    // Check if the JDK used supports JVMCI?
    String vm_version = System.getProperty("java.vm.version");
    System.out.printf("java.vm.version = %s%n", vm_version);

    HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class);

    // Is JVMCI enabled by default?
    VMOption enableJVMCI = bean.getVMOption("EnableJVMCI");
    System.out.println(enableJVMCI);

    // Is the system using the JVMCI compiler for normal compilations?
    VMOption useJVMCICompiler = bean.getVMOption("UseJVMCICompiler");
    System.out.println(useJVMCICompiler);

    // What compiler is selected?
    String compiler = System.getProperty("jvmci.Compiler");
    System.out.printf("jvmci.Compiler = %s%n", compiler);
}
```

(edit) With VM arguments as :

```
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+EnableJVMCI -XX:+UseJVMCICompiler
```

#### Java 10(2018-03-20) Result

> ```
> java.vm.version = 10+46
> VM option: EnableJVMCI value: true  origin: VM_CREATION (read-only)
> VM option: UseJVMCICompiler value: true  origin: VM_CREATION (read-only)
> jvmci.Compiler = null
> ```

#### Java 9.0.4 Result

> ```
> java.vm.version = 9.0.4+11
> VM option: EnableJVMCI value: true  origin: VM_CREATION (read-only)
> VM option: UseJVMCICompiler value: true  origin: VM_CREATION (read-only)
> jvmci.Compiler = null
> ```

but this is accompanied by logs which complains

> ```
> jdk.vm.ci.common.JVMCIError: no JVMCI compiler selected
>   at jdk.internal.vm.ci/jdk.vm.ci.hotspot.HotSpotJVMCICompilerConfig$DummyCompilerFactory.compileMethod(HotSpotJVMCICompilerConfig.java:45)
>   at jdk.internal.vm.ci/jdk.vm.ci.hotspot.HotSpotJVMCICompilerConfig$DummyCompilerFactory.compileMethod(HotSpotJVMCICompilerConfig.java:42)
>   at jdk.internal.vm.ci/jdk.vm.ci.hotspot.HotSpotJVMCIRuntime.compileMethod(HotSpotJVMCIRuntime.java:433)
> ```

When with both the versions the **`jvmci.Compiler`** value is **`null`**, what does *no JVMCI compiler selected* exactly mean here for 9.0.4(why not in 10)?

This might sound silly or unrelated, but am I falling back to the part where I should be aware of [Does Java 9 include Graal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252830/does-java-9-include-graal/48252959#48252959) ? Since I thought, even if 9.0.4 doesn't, I haven't specified the same on Java10 either(the `-Djvmci.Compiler` flag). Any default configurations that might have changed?

***Note***: Using MacOS(x64) for all of the above.