# How to integrate LLVM to JVM Runtime

Tags: java, jvm, llvm, jvm-hotspot

Is it possible to integrate LLVM with JVM Runtime.
I am interested in this perf optimization 
Azul Zing already does that but is possible to do it with Oracle's JVM or OpenJDK ?

Comment: This is crazy. Why is the question downvoted ?

Comment: The question could easily be seen as too broad or asking for off site resources. It is for sure not crazy to have some downvotes on it...

Comment: Especially in this context, this question does not require writing blog post and explaining every other detail.

Comment: You asked, and I gave an explanation. And I appreciate the quick comeback.

Comment: You could ask them for a trail license to see what difference it makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely to be feasible for you to integrate LLVM with OpenJDK or Oracle JDK.  (OpenJDK or Oracle JDK are pretty much the same thing anyway ... from a technical perspective.)

You would need to repeat all of the development work that the Azul team have done to get their LLVM-based compilers to work with a JVM.  That is unlikely to be practical for you.

> I am interested in this perf optimization Azul Zing already does that but is possible to do it with Oracle's JVM or OpenJDK ?

It may be possible<sup>1</sup> to implement those optimizations by modifying the existing OpenJDK code-base.

[GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) looks like another option.  (What GhostCat didn't mention in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231891/139985) is that GraalVM supports LLVM-based compilers.  So if you had an LLVM-based compiler for Java, you could use that as the basis for your optimizer work.)

---

<sup>1 - It is not clear whether Azul took the LLVM approach for technical reasons, or for licensing reasons, or both.  If they took the approach of modifying the OpenJDK JIT compiler, they would be obliged to publish their source code.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You simply start studying/using the graal [vm](https://www.graalvm.org/).

> Universal VM for a polyglot world. Our mission: Make development more productive and run programs faster anywhere.

( not to mix up with the graal [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252830/does-java-9-include-graal), a java-to-native compiler, which is already shipped with the JDK since Java 9 )

In other words: we are already on the move.

Comment: You mean GraalVM takes advantage of Sulong ? https://github.com/graalvm/sulong 
Please clarify. Will it be good as LLVM ?