# Does GraalVM JVM support java 11?

Tags: java, java-11, graalvm

How build **GraalVM JVM** for **Java 11**?

```
(I don't see any official distributives only java 8)
```

Comment: Related - [Does Java 9 include Graal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252830/does-java-9-include-graal)

Answer (score 16):

Not currently.

From this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/651), it seems that it will be ready around the end of February, 2019. However, Java 11 **does** include support for the Graal compiler, which can be enabled with the following flags:

```
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseJVMCICompiler
```

Edit: According to that GitHub issue, it looks like Graal 19.3 will be released on November 19, 2019, which should include Java 11 support.

Answer (score 4):

Yes the new version of GraalVM 19.3.0 supports Java 11.

please go to the below link for more information

https://medium.com/graalvm/graalvm-19-3-0-dfdb6f4ec8ed

Answer (score 0):

I am using java12 and i just added these  dependencies  to my project and it works fine

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graalvm.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>graal-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>19.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.js/js -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
        <artifactId>js</artifactId>
        <version>19.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.js/js-scriptengine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
        <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
        <version>19.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.compiler/compiler -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graalvm.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
        <version>19.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```